# Handling window popups in Selenium using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I am trying to pass values like First name,Last Name etc in a window popup. I am attaching the screenshot of the page. The Html code behind the page:

```
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="" onblur="capAll(this);" class="critfont" size="22" maxlength="16">
```

I tried inspecting it and copy the Xpath, but it is unable to find the Element and is throwing exception.

My C# code is:

```
var wa = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var LN = wa.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='pageBodyNoHeader']/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")));
LN.Click();
LN.SendKeys("Aerere")
```

When I am running this code, it is throwing me an exception that it has timed out after 10 secs.

I have also tried this code:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='pageBodyNoHeader']/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).Click();
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='pageBodyNoHeader']/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).SendKeys("Whatever");
```

Over here the exception that it throws is "It is unable to find the field name".

Can someone please help? Thank you[image]

In order to switch to the window popup, I have used the following code:

```
Driver.Instance.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.Instance.WindowHandles.Last());
Driver.Instance.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

Comment: Have you switched the context to the second window?

Comment: Yes, should I post the code of that as well?

Comment: It would help. As of now there's not enough information to solve your issue.

Comment: I posted the code. Kindly check

Comment: You need to call `driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);` to set the context, and not `Maximize();`

Comment: I forgot to add one line, it now updated.

Comment: Ya I have used that already, I just forgot to add that line. Its now updated. :)

Comment: Since the second window is not maximized on your screenshot, you probably need to wait for a second window.

Comment: I have used 10 seconds, its throwing me an exception saying its timed out after 10 seconds.

Comment: How many handles do you get with `Driver.Instance.WindowHandles` ?

Comment: I am getting 2, so I tried no to maximize and using the same commands, now its working fine though, but the moment I am trying to maximize..its trowing exception, saying timed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there may be problem in your `xpath`, you should try using `By.Name` as below :-

```
var wa = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var LN = wa.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Name("lastname")));
LN.Click();
LN.SendKeys("Aerere");
```

**Note** :- Make sure this element is not inside any `frame` or `iframe`. If it is inside then you need to switch that `frame` or `iframe` before finding element as :- `Driver.Instance.SwitchTo().Frame("frame name or id");`

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: Hey Saurabh, thanks for the answer..this is actually a very new thing for me and I am the only one in the project..you are just  saving my sanity again and again..:)

Comment: Currently I am facing another issue, can you please have a look at it.This is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38642940/handling-colors-in-a-window-popup-using-selenium-c-sharp